# Mathematica help ~ converting elements in a matrix to string

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have this 10x10 matrix (or Array) in Mathematica whose elements which have the value -1 or +1. I want to change all the -1 to a string " " (here its just the spacebar) and all the +1's to the symbol for addition, i.e "+". Any ideas on how I may achieve this?

Comment: new=old/.{-1 -> " ", 1-> "+"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yourArray /. { 1 -> "a", -1 -> "b" }` or similar.

See this and the related tutorials:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html

This is a fundamental part of Mathematica so it's one of the first things you should get familiar with.